# How do I download and build an edge version of an open source version of nvd3?

Tags: git, build, gruntjs, nvd3.js

I'm trying to use edge [nvd3](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/tree/refactor/2.0.0-dev) and I can't figure out how to actually build the JS file.

When I follow the (brief, unsatisfactory) directions they give and run grunt, it builds version 1.15, which is the latest stable version. I imagined when I cloned the repo that there might be a 2.0.0-dev branch I could merge into master, but all I see is master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your clone, git branch -r to see the other branches and the git checkout the name of the branch you want to work from.